# retrieve parent child records in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a similar data set table called "album"

```
album_id    parent_id   name
2           NULL        ...
34          NULL        ...
35          2       ...
36          2       ...
```

In php, my url looks like this: http://www.website/album.php?albumid=2

In other words, find the parent_id of the album_id 2 (which is null) and return parent/children:

```
album_id    parent_id   name
2           NULL        ...
35          2       ...
36          2       ...
```

When my url looks like this: http://www.website/album.php?albumid=35

find the parent_id of album_id 35 (which is 2) and return records were the album_id = 2 and the parent_id = 2 (parent/children):

```
album_id    parent_id   name
2           NULL        ...
35          2       ...
36          2
```

How would I do it in one query?

Comment: Can you explain it more? what is the name of the other table?

Comment: there is no other table, just table 'album'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT parent_id 
    FROM album
    WHERE album_id = 35
) AS t1 INNER JOIN album t2
  ON t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id OR t1.albumn_id = t1.parent_id;
```

Comment: actually, it did work. i´ve change the last part to make it work... thanks